# text overflows its parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a layout with 4 horizontally positioned div's like that: 
[image]

Now, when I add text and resize it with [big text](https://github.com/DanielHoffmann/jquery-bigtext/) to the light green div it expands somehow in a strange way (screenshot made on chrome):

[image]

Why is the text overflowing its parent?

I need the div's to stay fixed in their size. 
How can I achieve that?

```css
    .textContentContainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: aqua;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    .FirstSectionRow1 {
        width:100%;
        height:10%;
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }
    
    .FirstSectionRow2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        background-color:darkslategrey;
    }
    
    .FirstSectionRow3 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
        background-color: darkcyan;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size:1.2vh;
    }
    
    .FirstSectionRow4 {
        height:10%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkorchid;
    }
```

```html
<div class="textContentContainer">
    <div class="FirstSectionRow1 uppercase">
        <span class="FirstSectionHeaderText">SOME HEADER TEXT</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="FirstSectionRow2"></div>
    
    <div class="FirstSectionRow3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    
    <div class="FirstSectionRow4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: See if you can modify this fiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8L8a8q5v/

Comment: A simple guess but maybe is it due to your font-size in hv. Ty to put it in px just to see if there is a difference.

Comment: The font-size in css does not matter. The big text script overrides the font-size and sets a new one by itself

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve - you say you want the divs to stay fixed in size but you are using relative sizes.  If the big text plugin is resizing the green div, then that surely is what is causing the issue but as you haven't created an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't really add more weight to this comment